# How do I select distinct records

Tags: sql

I would like to select distinct record from my data, at the moment it displays repeated records. Here is how my query looks:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID,
  FirstName,
  SecondName,
  Department,
  Company,
  TotalEmployee,
  COUNT(
  CASE TotalAwards
    WHERE 1
    THEN 1
    ELSE NULL
  END),
  COUNT(
  CASE TotalRespect
    WHERE 1
    THEN 1
    ELSE NULL
  END)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY FirstName,
  SecondName,
  Department,
  Company,
  TotalEmployee
```

I have included distinct word but still I am getting repeated results

Comment: Can you give us an example? Distinct ensures that each row is unique

Comment: The query above is wrong and might not work at all. SELECT clause contains ID field but it is neither grouping criteria nor aggregate expression. Please repost real statement.

Comment: You should not be including ID if you are not intending on grouping by it.  Try not to use DISTINCT - it often hides duplicates.  Group by Creates intention.

Comment: DISTINCT makes no sense here. You get one record per group. There can be no duplicates. If you don't get the desired results it is likely you want to group by something else.

Comment: And why are u grouping and distincting ?

Answer (score 0):

DISTINCT key word use with that column which values you want to get distinct, ID is always distinct. as DISTINCT FirstName than first name will be distinct.

Answer (score 0):

You are either looking for:

```
SELECT FirstName,
  SecondName,
  Department,
  Company,
  TotalEmployee,
  COUNT(
  CASE TotalAwards
    WHERE 1
    THEN 1
    ELSE NULL
  END),
  COUNT(
  CASE TotalRespect
    WHERE 1
    THEN 1
    ELSE NULL
  END)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY FirstName,
  SecondName,
  Department,
  Company,
  TotalEmployee
```

OR

```
SELECT ID,
  FirstName,
  SecondName,
  Department,
  Company,
  TotalEmployee,
  COUNT(
  CASE TotalAwards
    WHERE 1
    THEN 1
    ELSE NULL
  END),
  COUNT(
  CASE TotalRespect
    WHERE 1
    THEN 1
    ELSE NULL
  END)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY ID, 
FirstName,
  SecondName,
  Department,
  Company,
  TotalEmployee
```

Comment: There's no reason to use both `DISTINCT` **AND** `GROUP BY` - records will be distinct after the `GROUP BY` evaluates.

Answer (score 0):

you could make use of row_number() and partition by() to get desired results

try like this:

```
select * from
(
select *,rn=row_number()over(partition by Totalawards,totalrespect order by Firstname)
from table
)x
where x.rn=1
```